# How do you denote the opposite of a range of numbers?

Tags: notation

What I want to do, is find the conventional standard to denote a range of numbers not included in a set, which is itself part of an infinate set.

For e.g:

A range of numbers, from say, -∞ to 0, and from 1,000,000 to ∞ i.e every number except, 1 through 1,000,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common notation would be $\mathbb Z\setminus\{1,2,3\}$ or $\mathbb Z-\{1,2,3\}$, where $\mathbb Z$ is the set of all integers. Notably, this would not include $\pm\infty$, since $\infty$ is not a number. Since this may get cumbersome if you wanted to leave out a lot of numbers-- say all the integers from one to one million--then you could say $\mathbb Z\setminus\{1,2,...,1{,}000{,}000\}$.

Sometimes sets of numbers are denoted $[a,b]$ for real numbers $a$ and $b$. This means the set of *all* numbers between $a$ and $b$ inclusive including decimals. Saying $\mathbb Z\setminus [1,10^6]$ still means the same thing, though because it indicates that we are removing all the numbers between $1$ and $10^6$ from $\mathbb Z$. If some of them weren't in $\mathbb Z$ to begin with, that is fine.

Comment: What if though, the range of numbers is much bigger? Say, from 1 to 1 million?

Comment: You could say [1,1000000] meaning all numbers from 1 to 1 million.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This is just a suggestion, but would ℤ-[0,10^6] suffice?

Comment: Yes, that is fine.

Comment: Sweet :) This seems like clever syntax as the ℤ seems to leave little to no room for ambiguity, and the syntax is kept short!

Answer (score 0):

Are you basically just asking for the complement?  So for instance $\{1,2,3\}^c$.

Comment: I have no idea :D

Comment: @user108262 Yeah, sounds like this is what you want.  $\{1, 2, 3\}^c$ means the set of all numbers not in $\{1,2, 3\}$.  You have to be careful, though, because its meaning depends on context.  For instance, does $\{1, 2, 3\}^c$ contain real numbers like $\pi$?  You have to make sure your audience knows what the background set is.  If the background set is $\mathbb{Z}$ then $\{1, 2, 3\}^c$ does not contain $\pi$ and if the background set is $\mathbb{R}$ then it does.

Comment: As another person answered, you can make the context unambiguous with the "set minus" notation, where $\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{1, 2, 3\}$ means "every integer but those in $\{1, 2, 3\}$".  This makes it explicit that the background set is $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering real numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then a common notation for "**all numbers except 1, 2 and 3**" is:

$$y \in (-\infty, 1) \cup (1, 2) \cup (2, 3) \cup (3, \infty).$$

This is called [**interval notation**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals).

Comment: The set brackets here seem to be a typo. If they are taken at face value, you're defining $y$ to be the set whose only element is the set $\mathbb R\setminus\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, you're right!  Will edit.

Comment: Of course, following Alex's answer, another way to write this is as $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{1,2,3\}$ or $\mathbb{R} - \{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to reverse the
direction of the brackets
and exchange
open and closed.

For example,
the complement of
"(0, 1]"
would be
"]0, 1(".

Comment: Is this notation ever used by anyone? There is a convention introduced by Bourbaki to use reversed square brackets to denote *open* intervals, that is, $[0,1]=\{x\in\mathbb R:0\le x\le1\}$ while $]0,1[=\{x\in\mathbb R:0<x<1\}$, which would conflict with your notation.